# Calling a paint or render method from another class - Java

Tags: java, swing

I did allot of research for this problem but couldn't find anything that would help me out.
When I run this app, the only thing I will see is an empty JFrame, the expected output is a JFrame with a black rectangle. This is my code, there are two classes.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test("Frame");
    test.setFrame();
    Window win = new Window(ObjectId.Window, 10, 10, 10, 10);
    win.repaint();
}

private String title;

public Test(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

private void setFrame() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

And my second class:

```
public class Window extends Component {

private ObjectId id;

private int x, y;
private int width, height;  

public Window(ObjectId id, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    this.id = id;

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You didn't add `win` to the frame ('s `contentPane`). And you should extend `JPanel` in the `Window`-class rather than `Component`.

Comment: @LuxxMiner Thanks! :)

Comment: @LuxxMiner write your comment as an answer so others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add `win` to the `frame` ('s `contentPane`). And you should extend `JPanel` in the `Window`-class, not `Component`.

So if you move `Window win = new Window(ObjectId.Window, 10, 10, 10, 10)` into the `setFrame()` method (you don't need the `win.repaint()`) and call `frame.getContentPane().add(win)` (or something similar) it will work.